# keep html elements in same row

Tags: html, css

Excuse this basic question, but I couldn't find an answer that fit.  I have this code in a view:

```
<div>  
   <h4> Irrelevant MVC code... </h4>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Accept</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Deny</button>
</div>
```

I would like the 2 buttons to appear next to the heading, not below. How would I do this please?

Comment: `div > * { display: inline-block }`

Comment: `h4 {display:inline-block}`

Answer (score 1):

Just add css property `display: inline-block;` to yours elements.
It's a method to display an element as a block while flowing it.
By default, your buttons are already inline, so you just need to display your `h4` inline :

```
h4{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

Because it is a [block element](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp), so your buttons come down.

```
h4{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you all. In case there are other beginners like me who got here from a search, the exact code i used for the tag is this:               <h4 style="display:inline-block">A heading</h4>